# Django, Pillow, NotImplementedError - absolute paths

Tags: image, storage, django-1.11

I'm uploading a user avatar to S3 after resizing. My ModelForm is as follow:

```
class UserAvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    x = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    y = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    width = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    height = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'img', 'x', 'y', 'width', 'height')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        photo = super(UserAvatarForm, self).save()

        x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
        y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
        w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
        h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

        image = Image.open(photo.img)
        cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
        resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        resized_image.save(photo.img.path)

        return photo
```

> NotImplementedError at /profile/avatar/ This backend doesn't support
>   absolute paths.

I've seen I can edit the save method to use [File Storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/), but I don't know how to implement it. Any help pls? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This made it working; I'll leave it here for future reference:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    photo = super(UserAvatarForm, self).save()

    x = self.cleaned_data.get('x')
    y = self.cleaned_data.get('y')
    w = self.cleaned_data.get('width')
    h = self.cleaned_data.get('height')

    image = Image.open(photo.img)
    cropped_image = image.crop((x, y, w+x, h+y))
    resized_image = cropped_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    storage_path = storage.open(photo.img.name, "wb")
    resized_image.save(storage_path, 'png')
    storage_path.close()

    return photo
```

Comment: Finally got the correct answer after trying lots of complicated way. Btw if anyone is finding how to import this storage.open(...... 'storage'. Use this
`` from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage ``  for Django == 2.2